# Hide/show the status bar in iOS 8 when full screen button pressed

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, statusbar

i've been searching through quite a lot of questions regarding this issue in iOS 8 here on stackOverflow, but i haven't quite found one that could help me fix my particular situation.

In my application i have a button that will enter a full screen mode, in this case it will just hide a navBar that i've coded and i'd like it to hide the status bar as well.

Using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

I am successfully able to hide the status bar and enter said full screen mode, the problem happens when try to leave that mode and use the counter instruction

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

This will work fine for the portrait orientation but if i rotate the device and go to landscape the usual default behaviour in iOS 8 is to hide the status bar but since i manually set it to NO in the instruction above it will overwrite that behaviour and it will always show the status bar on all the views in my app if i'm in landscape orientation.

So my question is, is there a way to restore the default behaviour of iOS 8 of hiding the status bar while in landscape?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with:

I use a UINavigationController as the "super controller" of all my view controllers.

I subclassed the UINavigationController. In there I implement `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` and in my view controllers I call:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return [self.navigationController prefersStatusBarHidden];
}
```

In the UINavigationController I do:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    BOOL phoneLandscape = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) > CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame);
    return _shouldHideStatusBar || phoneLandscape;
}
```

Where the `_shouldHideStatusBar` ivar determines if the bar should be hidden or not.

Of course you need to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES`.

Perfectly mimics the iOS 8 behavior and you can even animate the status bar using `- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation`.

The only problem is interactively showing and hiding the bar during view controller transitions. Not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after a bit of brainstorming as to how to hide the status bar without using the

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

so that it doesn't override the default behaviour of iOS 8, i researched a bit more and what i did was stretch the view so it takes up the entire screen (with the status bar height) and then i had to make sure that the

```
self.view.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
```

view window level was set so that it would essentially cover the status bar, this way whenever i enter the full screen mode my view goes on top of the status bar and whenever i leave it all i have to do is set the window level back to normal using

```
self.view.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
```

with these instructions i was able to emulate the full screen mode that i wanted without altering the actual behaviour of iOS 8 when changing to landscape and hiding the status bar.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Even using -prefersStatusBarHidden doesn't result in the iOS 8 behavior, even though I feel like it should. I guess with your solution, there is no way of animating the status bar in and out? Have you encountered any problems with your solution?

Comment: So far i haven't had any problems with the solution i encountered, i know it's not the "cleanest" solution and the most pretty one but it works for what i really wanted which was to emulate a full screen mode.